# How to create a map of smart pointers that deletes its elements when the pointers go out of scope

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unordered-map

I want to a map container that takes a smart pointer to a custom type. When you put the key in, you get `shared_ptrs` to the object, but when all of those `shared_ptrs` go out of scope, the object is destroyed inside the map (in contrast to a normal map, where the object persists until the map goes out of scope or until it is explicitly deleted).

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
SpecialMap<int, std::string> map;

{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> item = map.getElement(3);

}                 // element at 3 is deleted *inside the map* here, because the pointer goes out of scope.

assert(map.getSize() == 0);
```

I think that this can be done by giving the map a member type of `std::weak_ptr`, which doesn't increment the reference count, and then using a `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter which removes the element from the map, rather than calling `delete`. But I'm struggling with how to insert items to the map. Here's what I'm trying right now.

(In this example I'm just using `int` and `string` to keep things simple--I'll template it properly later on).

```
class SpecialMap
{

public:

    std::shared_ptr<std::string> getElement(int i)
    {
        auto result = map.try_emplace(i, std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("text"),

            [this](std::string* s)  // here is the custom deleter
        {
            for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();)
            {
                if (&*it->second.lock() == s)
                {
                    map.erase(it);
                    return;
                }
                else ++it;
            }
        }));

        return result.first->second.lock();
    }

    int getSize() const
    { return map.size(); }

private:

    std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<std::string>> map;
};
```

This code doesn't work because the `shared_ptr` inside `try_emplace` goes out of scope immediately, deleting the item before it can be returned.

Can anyone suggest a better way of interacting with `unordered_map` here? Or is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: I think its pretty useful. Its a caching mechanism where there's a central repository which can give out references to objects, creating them if necessary, but importantly not keeping them alive if no one else has a reference to them. @idmean

Comment: @MikeVine Yes, I agree, that makes sense. I think I misunderstood OP when I first read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following part of the deleter...

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();) {
    if (&*it->second.lock() == s) {
        map.erase(it);
        return;
    }
    else
         ++it;
}
```

But the deleter is only being called because the ref  count has become zero.  That being the case the call...

```
it->second.lock()
```

will return a shared pointer that refers to a null pointer.  Hence the equality will never hold and the corresponding element in the unordered_map will never be erased.

The usual way to deal with something like this would be to have something like...

```
using container_type = std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<foo>>;
container_type                                  m_map;
std::map<foo *, container_type::const_iterator> m_iters;
```

Here `m_map` is the *real* data store and `m_iters` can be used to find the appropriate iterator to erase when the shared pointers ref count becomes zero and the deleter is called.

```
class special_map {
  using container_type = std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<std::string>>;
public:
  using const_iterator = container_type::const_iterator;

  std::shared_ptr<std::string> get_element (int i)
    {

      /*
       * Check to see if the requested element already exists.  If so simply
       * return it.
       */
      auto iter = m_map.find(i);
      if (iter != m_map.end())
        return iter->second.lock();
      std::shared_ptr<std::string> value(
        new std::string,
        [this](std::string *s)
          {
            std::cout << "deleter called on " << s << "\n";
            if (auto i = m_iters.find(s); i != m_iters.end()) {
              m_map.erase(i->second);
              m_iters.erase(i);
            }
            delete s;
          });
      iter = m_map.emplace(i, value).first;
      auto sp = iter->second.lock();
      m_iters[sp.get()] = iter;
      return sp;
    }
  int get_size() const
    {
      return m_map.size();
    }
  const_iterator begin () const
    {
      return m_map.begin();
    }
  const_iterator end () const
    {
      return m_map.end();
    }
private:
  container_type                                          m_map;
  std::map<std::string *, container_type::const_iterator> m_iters;
};

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, const special_map &v)
{
  std::cout << "special_map@" << &v << "(" << v.get_size() << " elements)...\n";
  for (const auto &i: v) {
    auto sp = i.second.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << i.first << "] --> [std::string@" << sp.get() << "/" << (sp.use_count() - 1) << "]\n";
  }
  return os << "\n";
}

int main ()
{
  {
    special_map sm;
    {
      auto s1 = sm.get_element(5);
      std::cout << sm;
      {
        auto s2 = sm.get_element(5);
        std::cout << sm;
      }
      std::cout << sm;
    }
    std::cout << sm;
  }
}
```

Example output from this is...

```
special_map@0x7ffedf44d6a0(1 elements)...
[5] --> [std::string@0xf75bc0/1]

special_map@0x7ffedf44d6a0(1 elements)...
[5] --> [std::string@0xf75bc0/2]

special_map@0x7ffedf44d6a0(1 elements)...
[5] --> [std::string@0xf75bc0/1]

deleter called on 0xf75bc0
special_map@0x7ffedf44d6a0(0 elements)...
```

**Edit 1**

If the key type being used is sufficiently 'lightweight' as with `int` in the current case then it might be possible to avoid the use of the extra `m_iters` container by having the deleter lambda capture the key by value and performing the map lookup based on that.  In that case the code becomes...

```
class special_map {
  using container_type = std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<std::string>>;
public:
  using const_iterator = container_type::const_iterator;

  std::shared_ptr<std::string> get_element (int i)
    {

      /*
       * Check to see if the requested element already exists.  If so simply
       * return it.
       */
      auto iter = m_map.find(i);
      if (iter != m_map.end())
        return iter->second.lock();
      std::shared_ptr<std::string> value(
        new std::string,
        [this, i](std::string *s)
          {
            std::cout << "deleter called on " << s << "\n";
            m_map.erase(i);
            delete s;
          }
        );
      return m_map.emplace(i, value).first->second.lock();
    }
  int get_size() const
    {
      return m_map.size();
    }
  const_iterator begin () const
    {
      return m_map.begin();
    }
  const_iterator end () const
    {
      return m_map.end();
    }
private:
  container_type m_map;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first line of code you've written is "using container_type std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<foo>>;". Looks like there's a = missing there. Could you edit it?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there is another possible solution that doesn't require two containers. But if not, this one will do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is memory leak in your code, becouse there is no delete in your custom delter object which receives pointer, so I added to your code delete operator.

And As good as I understand you, you should store your pointer into variable first, and then try to emplace it into your map, so it should looks like this

```
class SpecialMap
{
public:

    std::shared_ptr<std::string> getElement(int i)
    {
        auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("Hello"),

            [this](std::string* s)  // here is the custom deleter
        {
            std::cout << "custom deleter is called\n";
            for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();)
            {
                if (&*it->second.lock() == s)
                {
                    map.erase(it);
                    return;
                }
                else ++it;
            }
            delete s;
        });
        auto result = map.try_emplace(i, ptr);

        return result.first->second.lock();
    }

    int getSize() const
    { return map.size(); }

private:

    std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<std::string>> map;
};

int main()
{
    SpecialMap map;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::string> item = map.getElement(3);
        std::cout << "some work with your ptr\n";
    }                 // element at 3 is deleted *inside the map* here, because the pointer goes out of scope.

}
```

And the output should be like this

```
some work with your ptr
custom deleter is called
```

Here is some [live](https://godbolt.org/z/6bsvsf) example with custom class

Comment: Thanks for spotting the leak. In this version the shared_ptr string will get constructed newly every time, even when I am retrieving an existing value, which seems sub-optimal. What is the best way of searching first to see if a new element needs to be inserted, and then inserting it only if need be?

Comment: @LiamGoodacre try_emplace will return iterator to existing element, if such exist(and do nothing more), so you should check element on existing before creating your new string. I edited live example in my answer, so it checks on existing before creating string(in my case custom struct). And BTW, now you can use emplace instead of try_emplace

Comment: Probably better would be to use `lower_bound` (or `upper`) for the initial find, and then if a create & insert is needed then to use the returned iterator from `lower_bound` as a hint to the `insert`. This will save looking up in the tree twice.

Comment: @MikeVine there is no ```lower_bound``` for ```unordered_map```, but we can use ```equal_range``` to find every member with with our key, but idk how to use this for cases where key is not existing, because order in unordered_map is not guaranteed

Comment: @БогданХмельницький you're right - I assumed it was a standard map from the title.

Comment: @MikeVine with unordered map you instead do an insert and check the boolean part of the return pair. In this case it is possible to insert a null weak pointer and then assign it `ptr` if `inserted` in `auto [pos, inserted] = map.insert(int, nullptr);` is true. The iterators are invalidated on a rehash. If they were never invalidated, you can safely pass the iterator to the deleter and avoid an extra search in there.